# Python: Variable defined in one function is not recognized in another function

Tags: python, function

```
class TestUM(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_Dynasty_init(self):
        try:
            self.p = ModelInterface(r"E:\HIL\07_Tests\AT_Dynasty_models\AT745\RTM_AT_745.dml") #any dml file should do here
        except Exception:
            self.fail("Dynasty initialization raised ExceptionType unexpectedly!")

    def test_Dynasty_check(self):
        self.p.check()
```

At line 9 I am getting the following error:

```
"AttributeError: 'TestUM' object has no attribute 'p'"
```

I don't understand. `self.p` is not getting recognized in the `test_Dynasty_check` function.

Comment: Those are two *separate* test cases.

Comment: Each test method is called on a separate instance of `TestUM`. Either rename `test_Dynasty_init` to `setUp`, or combine the two into a single method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `setUp()` and `tearDown()` for initialization/destruction code.

If I remember correctly, the `unittest` library runs all functions starting with `test` in alphabetical order.  Meaning that `test_Dynasty_check` is running before `test_Dynasty_init`.  **EDIT:** The order doesn't matter, since each test will be run from a *new* instance of the TestCase class.

Comment: I wouldn't even count on the test methods being executed in any particular order. Individual tests should be independent of each other.

Answer (score 0):

That probably depends on whether test_Dynasty_init() is actually called before test_Dynasty_check() for your class instance.